# Log4J2 Configuration fails: Log4J2 RabbitMQ Appender with Spring-AMQP/Spring-Rabbit

Tags: java, rabbitmq, log4j2, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to integrate a Log4J2 Appender to RabbitMQ in an already working and logging java application.

The application is build as a gradle project. Before the integration of spring-rabbit, the `build.gradle` file looked like this:

```
group 'Name'
version '1.18.7'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    [...]
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'com.lmax', name: 'disruptor', version: '3.3.7'
    [...]
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'the.main.Clazz'
    }
}


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins', name: 'shadow', version: '2.0.2'
    }
}
```

The log4j2.xml file, positioned in the `src/resources` folder, contains this (before rabbitMQ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration monitorInterval="15">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%highlight{%-6p}{STYLE=DEFAULT, noConsoleNoAnsi=true}] %C{1}.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n%throwable</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <RandomAccessFile name="ASYNC_FILE" fileName="logs/app.log" immediateFlush="false" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%-6p] %C{1}.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n%throwable</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="my.package" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC_FILE"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The application runs nicely, as well as from the IDE and the JAR, built with the shadowJar plugin.

Now, the mystery begins. Simply by adding the `spring-rabbit` dependency...

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.amqp', name: 'spring-rabbit', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
```

...logging starts to behave very strange. Started from the IDE, everything works still nice. Adding the following appender to the `log4j2.xml` works fine:

```
    <RabbitMQ name="RABBIT_MQ"
              host="my.host.name" port="5672" user="logger" password="logger" virtualHost="loggerhost"
              exchange="logs" exchangeType="fanout" declareExchange="false"
              applicationId="app-xyz" routingKeyPattern="%X{applicationId}.%c.%p"
              contentType="text/plain" contentEncoding="UTF-8" generateId="true" deliveryMode="NON_PERSISTENT"
              charset="UTF-8"
              senderPoolSize="3" maxSenderRetries="5">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d [%-6p] %C{1}.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n%throwable</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </RabbitMQ>
```

I see the log messages delivered via the RabbitMQ server.

But when I build and run the JAR file built with `:shadowJar`, logging stops working. On STDOUT, I see the following:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
```

When I start the application JAR with the `-Dlog4j2.debug` option I see a lot of messages, and some seem to say, that the configuration cannot be loaded (which is still at the same place). Here an excerpt:

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@2a33fae0
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
```

I even used the `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` option, pointing directly to the XML in the file system, but the result stays the same.

Again, starting the application from the IDE and not via `java -jar ...` works fine. It seems to me as if the `spring-rabbitmq` dependency brings some extra log4j stuff that interferes with my configuration. I'm totally fishing in murky waters.

Comment: Could you, please, share with us on the GitHub the project to play with on our side? And some instructions how to reproduce. Thanks

Comment: Try using the `-verbose` JVM arg and compare the class loading of the log4j stuff - the spring-rabbit dependency is `optional` so it shouldn't bring in any log4j jars.

Comment: Try removing `PatternLayout` elements from `RabbitMQ` appender configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of research I can answer my question with the following.

It is ***not*** enough to simply add the Spring-Rabbit-MQ `org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit` dependency to let the Log4J2 configuration fail. It's the combination with another dependency, that is not listed in my example: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind`.

To sum it up. This does not work:

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.3'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'com.lmax', name: 'disruptor', version: '3.3.7'
compile group: 'org.springframework.amqp', name: 'spring-rabbit', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
```

But this works (without Spring):

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.3'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'com.lmax', name: 'disruptor', version: '3.3.7'
```

And this works (without Jackson):

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'com.lmax', name: 'disruptor', version: '3.3.7'
compile group: 'org.springframework.amqp', name: 'spring-rabbit', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
```

So the combination of Jackson and Spring breaks Log4J2. Interestingly, without Jackson, my program works as well, even if Jackson is under heavy use. Let's have a look on that, what `gradle dependecies` has to say:

```
compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.10.0
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0
+--- com.lmax:disruptor:3.3.7
\--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.0.2.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:2.0.2.RELEASE
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.0.3.RELEASE
     +--- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.1.2
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.8.0-alpha2
     +--- com.rabbitmq:http-client:1.3.1.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3
     |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6
     |    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
     |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9 -> 1.11
     |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.2
     |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
     |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.2
     +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.1.RELEASE
          \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
```

Oh, wait, there's also a Jackson within the Spring AMQP. Well, that solves the riddle, why I can still use Jackson after removing the dependency. But this is very intransparent to me and depends on the Spring AMQP package to deliver a core dependency for me. So what I finally did is this, and it seems to work:

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.3'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'com.lmax', name: 'disruptor', version: '3.3.7' version: '2.12.0'
compile (group: 'org.springframework.amqp', name: 'spring-rabbit', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE') {
    exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
}
```

The dependency tree looks like the following now:

```
compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.3
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.10.0
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0
+--- com.lmax:disruptor:3.3.7
\--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.0.2.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:2.0.2.RELEASE
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.0.3.RELEASE
     +--- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.1.2
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.8.0-alpha2
     +--- com.rabbitmq:http-client:1.3.1.RELEASE
     |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3
     |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6
     |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
     |         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9 -> 1.11
     +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.3.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.1.RELEASE
          \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 5.0.3.RELEASE (*)
```

I must admit that I not fully understand why the combination of two Jackson dependencies brings the Log4J2 configuration down, but now it works with this strategy:

- Declare Jackson dependency explicitly (make transparent, that the application uses Jackson)
- Exclude Jackson from Spring dependency

And what I really don't get: Why do all combinations work from within the IDE, but later fail when running the JAR?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-954) with log4j, reported over 3 years ago. It comes up when you use the shadowjar plugin. See shadowjar issue [here](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/207).

You can read both tickets to get a better understanding, but if you're looking for a point-and-click solution, just use [this](https://github.com/TheBoegl/shadow-log4j-transformer) gradle plugin:

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "2.0.2"
  id "de.sebastianboegl.shadow.transformer.log4j" version "2.2.0"
}
```

... or revert to log4j 2.0.2.